# How can I prevent a user from saving a document in SwiftUI?

Tags: macos, cocoa, swiftui

I'm building a document-based app with SwiftUI on MacOS Big Sur.  I want to prevent users from saving the files as it is intended only as a viewer.  How can I do this in SwiftUI?

I'm forced to implement the writing method due to the protocol `FileDocument`

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyDoc: FileDocument {
    static var readableContentTypes: [UTType]
    
    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        <#code#> // reading
    }
    
    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        <#code#> // writing
    }
    
}
```

My app looks something like this

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyDocApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(viewing: MyDoc.self) { file in
            ContentView(document: file.$document)
        }
    }
}
```

I've already selected 'Read Only' in 'Signing and Capabilities'

[image: app requirements]

I'm not sure how else to prevent this in SwiftUI.

Cmd+S triggers the save behaviour and the menu options are still included.

Here's a sample project demonstrating the issue - [Sample Project](https://github.com/conorgriffin/MyDoc)

I guess one option is to throw an error in the write method and handle it telling the user they aren't allowed to save files.  But this seems a bit... hacky!

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way either, and ended up doing the-hacky-way:

```
struct MyDoc: FileDocument {

    ...

    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        throw CocoaError(.fileWriteNoPermission)
    }
}
```

At least it's readable

Comment: yeah I did the same, can't believe this hasn't either been fixed or identified as something I'm doing wrong :|